# osx Terminal new tab in same directory

Tags: macos, tabs, terminal

I am not going to be the first to ask this but I have been trying to solve this googleing a lot and none of the resources has been useful. My problem is simple (to explain), I want to open a new tab in the same directory in the Terminal app. Now, every tab I open is opened in my ~ directory. I have also tried with iTerm2 but still the same problem. This is my .bash_profile:

```
# Git configuration
parse_git_branch() {
    git branch 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/(\1) /'
}

# Command line prompt
PS1='[\t] \[\e[0;32m\]\u@\h\[\e[m\]:\w \[\e[0;34m\]$(parse_git_branch)\[\e[m\]> '

# virtualenvwrapper
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh

# alias for mysql
alias mysql=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
alias mysqladmin=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin
alias mysqlstart='sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start'
alias mysqlstop='sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server stop'

export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
```

Thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/148508/how-to-open-a-new-tab-in-iterm-in-the-same-folder-as-the-one-that-is-open

Comment: I had already seen that post but I don't have that option in Preferences, but that's because I am using Terminal instead of iTerm.

Comment: OK. But you wrote "I have also tried with iTerm2 but still the same problem."

Comment: Well, this is not exactly what I was looking for because I wanted to solve the problem for Terminal. But thank you for the link, for iTerm works fine so I will use iTerm. Let's see if somebody knows how to solve the problem with Terminal.

Comment: Hello, I know that you posted this several years ago but I have a solution that worked for me. Hopefully, you're well past the problem but if not give it a shot and lemme know if it works for you!

Answer (score 7):

So, I had this problem and actually just solved it. I know this post is old but if it helps anyone else I'll be happy.

I found out that if you have spaces in your hostname it breaks the `New tab in the same directory` feature that comes with the terminal.

Here are a couple examples. My `.bash_profile` is edited and changes how my prompt looks a little so I have two examples in each. **You're gonna wanna focus on `Kippins MacBook Pro` part. This shouldn't have spaces!!!**

**BAD EXAMPLES!**

```
Last login: Sat Oct 19 22:59:36 on ttys004
kippins@Kippins MacBook Pro:~$

Last login: Sat Oct 19 23:06:32 on ttys000
Kippins MacBook Pro:~ kippins$
```

**GOOD EXAMPLES!**

```
Last login: Sat Oct 19 22:59:36 on ttys004
kippins@Kippins-MacBook-Pro:~$

Last login: Sat Oct 19 23:06:32 on ttys000
Kippins-MacBook-Pro:~ kippins$
```

If you've already checked that your settings in `Terminal > Preferences > General` are correct. See the picture in the link below (My rep isn't high enough to embed pictures). You want `New tabs open with:` section to be set to `Same Profile` and `Same Working Directory`

[Correct Terminal Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhknU.png)

If you have spaces in your terminal hostname I think your problem is the same as mine and here's how I fixed it. In the terminal enter the following commands with the `"Name-With-No-Spaces"` part subbed in with a name of your choosing **with no spaces!!!** You'll need root access for this.

```
sudo scutil --set ComputerName "Name-With-No-Spaces"
sudo scutil --set LocalHostName "Name-With-No-Spaces"
sudo scutil --set HostName "Name-With-No-Spaces"
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

After doing all of this you'll need to restart your Mac. Hopefully, in the end, you'll have fixed your issue. I went through months of digging and had come across this post several times and I feel like the question most accurately describes what I was going through.

Answer (score 2):

Just the quoted part for `PS1` works for me to open tabs in the same folder.  The answer by grgarside in *[How to open a new Terminal tab in current working directory?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/128998/how-to-open-a-new-terminal-tab-in-current-working-directory)* suggests that something may have altered `PROMPT_COMMAND`; for instance in the `virtualenvwrapper.sh` script.

An easy way to troubleshoot this problem would be to start with a *simpler* `.bash_profile` (first empty, to verify that the open-with-same-pwd feature works), and then adding parts to see what breaks it.

Comment: I already tried to empty the .bash_profile and adding content. Nevertheless, since iTerm works correctly means that is not related to the .bash_profile file. Thanks.

Comment: I found that including `export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'` in my `.profile` caused Terminal to stop setting the right path for a new tab (it always opened in the home directory, even with "New tabs open with: Same Working Directory" set). This also prevented the directory location from being restored when Terminal restarted and restored previous windows.

Comment: Thank you @matthias-fripp for the hint. That was also my case.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and found that the problem was in the random zsh theme i had set up in .zshrc. After setting my theme to a specific value, new tabs were opened in the same directory.